# Overriding Bootstrap has-error class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in Rails which has a field named Amount. I insert commas to the input field as user enters the amount. Both HTML and Javascript code are given below:

```
<div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 form-group' id="amount_div">
    <%=f.text_field_without_bootstrap :amount, required:true, class: 'form-control' %>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>


$('#amount').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
    a = $('#amount').val().replace(/\,/g,'');
    if(a!=""){
        b = parseInt(a);
        console.log(b);
        if(b>100000){
            $("#amount_div").addClass("has-error");
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the problem is, after user enters the amount I want to check if the entered amount is greater than 100000. And if it is greater, I want to show this error to user and disable the submit button in this case. Bootstrap has a inbuilt class for the same called "has-error". Whenever any field lacks any validation, a new class gets appended to the div called  "has-error", the error is shown to the user besides the input field and submit button gets disabled. I want to have the same functionality for amount field after user enters the amount.

I am appending has-error class to my div but if I click anywhere outside the amount inut field, the class is gone. I don't understand the problem. If my understanding regarding appending the error class is wrong, kindly correct me. Thanks!

Comment: are you using `bootstrap validator`?

Comment: Yes. I am using this { toggle: 'validator' }

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this behaviour because you are using bootstrap validator. `has-error` is the default error class added by bootstrap validator to your `form-group` when your input is invalid based on  the validation rules you provide on the input. The error class is added or removed accordingly by the validator every time you focus out *(on blur*) the input field or submit the form. Since you don't have any validation rules on the input, bootstrap validator consider the input as valid and removes the class.
To fix this behaviour you can actually use the `.max` on input to make the the validation handled automatically the bootstrap validator. So just change

```
<%=f.text_field_without_bootstrap :amount, required:true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

to

```
<%=f.number_field_without_bootstrap :amount, required:true, class: 'form-control', max: 100000 %>.
```

Or you can write some custom css to add the error border and add that class to the input which bootstrap validator won't be aware of. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot apply commas if I use number field instead of text field. 
I am just trying to find a way to notify user that input field is wrong, somehow in a similar fashion as done by Bootstrap.

Comment: @Yesha Ohh..Okay. Then you have to write a custom css class and add it to the input instead of `has-error` as I mentioned or add a custom validation statement to the validator. By the way which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I am using version 3.2.0
Also, can you please explain what do you mean by "add a custom validation statement to the validator"?